# Images on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue best shown by example: http://dont.net/DesigningIntro/index.html

Here the last "Car Exterior" is opened fully, but not properly opens as like other small bars. It gets hidden while hovering on other links.

I want it to be shown, and not get hidden even if I hover on other tabs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is the `car_L.jpg` image in the `.jimgMenu ul li.car_ext a` element is being moved to the next line when it animates somehow due to the `min-width` css tag.  Removing that causes the image to be set to just `56px` wide by the animation when not hovering on it.  Not what you want.

However, I kind of made it work by setting the background image for the `.jimgMenu` Div.  See the result here: http://jsbin.com/ayutu and code here: http://jsbin.com/ayutu/edit

Comment: Oh dear, thanks a lot, thanks a lot. You have done a great job for me. I am a web designer and working since 2007. 

This is my some of creative web designs. If you need any website  design please let me know.... it will be free to you.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/40193310@N05/sets/72157621801792608/detail/

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure whether this is causing your issue or not, but it looks like you have the ending of a comment tag before your  tag.  I would try removing that and see if it fixes the problem first.

[image]

Comment: Nothing happened dear, even removing the highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are forgetting the image for "Car Exterior" of 56x330px? Also, you don't have an image with vertical letters for "Interior".

Then you are not referencing them well, because if I search images on your page with the Firefox's add-on Web Developer Toolbar it doesn't find the images Car Exterior or Interior.

Answer (score 0):

When you first come into the page there are 9 accordion panels.  when you hover over one there are only eight.

So, do you have the control setup for 9 panels even when you hover?  maybe you need to clear out the last panel on hover so the control knows to reclaim the space and then put it back on mouse out.

the next issue then might be that the control will resize because now the last panel is missing so the max width will be less.

Comment: if i send you the zip file, can you please sort out ? Because I am trying since last 2 hrs. But all in vain.

Comment: I could have a go yeah!  But I'm kinda at work so I'm not really in a position to give it my 100% attention.

Comment: I can't give out my email, for obvious reasons, so you'll have to make it available some other way that I can get to.  Remember that (everything) you post here is open to the whole world to see.  Unsure how you want to progress with this.